# Pass a string from one class to another class

Tags: java

I have checked the tutorials and this should work but it doesn't. I have a string in one class that I want to use in another, but when I do, I get a null exception.

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean
public class FileDirectoryViewer {
FileUploadController destination = new FileUploadController();

        NewDestination = destination + username + "/";
```

And I am trying to get the destination from

```
@ViewScoped
@ManagedBean(name = "fileUploadController")
public class FileUploadController {

    public String destination  = "D:/Documents/NetBeansProjects/printing~subversion/fileupload/Uploaded/"; // main location for uploads
```

How do I get the destination from `FileUploadController` to `FileDirectoryViewer`?

Comment: Your tutorials might not be ideal.  There are a few things wrong here.   In your first snippet `String newDestination = destination.destination + username + "/";` would work, but still leaves alot to be desired.

Comment: Hi there what is wrong with this code ? sorry i am new to all this Thanks :)

Comment: @user2061913, string field named `destination` and FileUploadController instance named `destination` are not the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `destination` field of `FileUploadController`, has no access modifier, so it is package private by default.

If those two classes are in the same package, you can access it by creating an instance of the class, and using the `.` operator on the instance to access the property:

```
FileUploadController controller = new FileUploadController();
NewDestination = controller.destination + username + "/";
```

If they are not, you should implement a `public String getDestination()` method in `FileUploadController` that would return `destination`. You should call this method also by using the `.` operator: `controller.getDestination()`.

Take into account there are several issues with the code you posted:

- You're placing code outside a method in the `FileDirectoryViewer` class. In a class you can only define members (such as fields, or methods). Generally speaking, behavorial code goes inside of method declarations.
- Using a hardcoded variable for a path property can be considered bad practice. Look into `java.util.Properties` for a start. Anyway, by the looks of the code, it doesn't make sense for the `destination` field to be an instance field, it could be `static` or defined in an `interface`.
- Naming conventions for java recommend variable names to be camel case, and starting with lower case letters.

Comment: Thanks a lot solved :D, i understand what i did wrong thanks !

Comment: @user2061913 Glad that helped :) Remember to upvote the answers you found to be helpful, and to accept the one you think is best by toggling the green checkmark below the answer vote counter.